# Redundancy level on a per file basis with BTRFS?

Tags: linux, raid, redundancy, mirroring, btrfs

I would like to have one storage pool with multiple disks.
Raid5 for metadata of course. But for user-data I would like to set the level of redundancy on a per file or per subvolume level.
Can BTRFS do this?

In ZFS there is a 'copies' attribute that is supposed to have this effect. The BTRFS wiki page lists the feature "File Mirroring". But does that refer to full data mirroring or actually on a per file basis?

Comment: “Raid5 for metadata of course.” – Metadata is important and relatively small. It would have a very high importance/size ratio so wouldn't you want RAID 1 for metadata?

Answer (score 4):

The per-file mirroring feature doesn't appear to be implemented yet.

[*If everything is RAID-1 (or RAID-0, or in general all the same RAID level), then yes, we could give a sane and consistent value from df. However, **we have plans to allow per-subvolume and per-file RAID levels.** In this case, it becomes impossible to give a sensible estimate as to how much space there is left.*](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Why_is_free_space_so_complicated.3F)

If you need this functionality **now**, [ZFS on Linux](http://zfsonlinux.org) is very stable (and probably a better bet in terms of completed features and mindshare).